# CKeditor Inline editing

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, autosave, inline-editing

I have the following source:

```
<div id="editable" runat="server" contenteditable="true" >Sample Text</div>
```

My question is if I can save the edited text with asp.net only?

If yes, what should be the source? If not there is any other simple way to save the edited data to database?

Comment: What do you mean asp.net only? I would imagine asp.net implies HTML, so I would imagine that it implies JavaScript as well, right?

Comment: @Nenotlep Yes, You write, I mean is it possible to get the whole new string text with C# code?

Comment: When CKEditor contains content is stored within the browser. What exactly do you want to do with it? Read it into a C# variable and save to DB/file? Can there be a POST? Can there be JavaScript? Using *ONLY* C# you cannot get the information, but I really, really don't think that pure c# is a true requirement for you.

Comment: @Nenotlep Hi, Thanks you for your answer, That is what I want to do. Get it to variable and save to DB, I seached in the web, and couldn't find anything helpfull (not with C# only). It will be more than OK to use JavaScript or ajax, I just don't know how should I do that, Is it even possible?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you so much, this is a complex issue :) I added a link to my answer that might be very useful for you as a very basic guide. It doesn't deal with the backend solution at all but it shows one example how to post. I think a tutorial would be more suitable than a code solution maby?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net is a framework, not a language. "Asp.net only" could really mean anything as it can contain Visual Basic, C#, HTML or JavaScript at the very least. "Asp.net" could also mean Asp.net MVC 3 with Razer or Asp.net Webforms (which I think you use based on `runat="server"`).

I'd say it's too much asking for the SO community to code the entire feature for you  to be honest, but my suggestion is to use inline JavaScript like suggested in http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Inline-editing-toolbar-has-no-save-icon

JavaScript is just as much a part of asp.net as other techniques in my opinnion.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I meant to aspx/C#, 
I tried the solution it this question but it just didn't work for me, is thara any other way to get the text (Javascript? AJAX?)

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but you may use some jquery ajax on that. You will get the value by using $(#divid).html() or $(#divid).text() then pass it to ajax then post it to a webservice.